# Testing Angular Factory (which uses other services) with Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha, angular-mock

I'm trying to test a bunch of Angular Services using Karma but it keeps running into errors. Basically I have files called "**APIHelper.js**" and "**Config.js**". Within these files, I have created factories namely "**APIHelper**" and "**Config**" respectively.
Now I have another file "XFactory.js" which defines another factory which actually uses "**APIHelper**" and "**Config**".

I've tested the APIHelper and Config factories, I know how to inject simple factory and test it. However, I'm having trouble testing this "**XFactory**" which has other dependencies.

Here's the code for APIHelper.js:

```
angular.module('Test').factory('APIHelper', function() {

    appendContext:function(item, context){
        //code here
    }
});
```

Here's the code for Config.js

```
angular.module('TesterLib',[]).factory('Configuration', function() {
      //code here
});
```

Here's the code for XFactory:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Test').factory('XFactory', function ($q, $http, APIHelper, Config) {

  function executeRequest(req) {
    .....
    .....
    //make the http call.
    var response = $http(convertedRequest);
    var deffered= $q.defer();

    response.then(function(resp){

      context.response = response;

      //Append the context to the body for easy access
      APIHelper.appendContext(response.body,context);
      deffered.resolve(response);

    },function(resp){
      //Create error
      var error = {message:resp.body,code:resp.statusCode};

      //Append the context to the error object
      APIHelper.appendContext(error,context);
      deffered.reject(error);
    });

      return deffered.promise;
  }

  return executeRequest;

});


    function executeRequest(req) {

        //Convert abstracted request to request's http request
        var convertedRequest = convertHttpRequest(req);

        //create a context to hold raw request and response
        var context = new HttpContext();
        context.request = req;

        //make the http call.
        var response = $http(convertedRequest);
        var deffered= $q.defer();

        response.then(function(resp){

            var response = convertHttpResponse(resp);
            context.response = response;

            //Append the context to the body for easy access
            APIHelper.appendContext(response.body,context);
            deffered.resolve(response);

        },function(resp){
            var response = convertHttpResponse(resp);
            context.response = response;
            //Create error
            var error = {message:response.body,code:response.statusCode};

            //Append the context to the error object
            APIHelper.appendContext(error,context);
            deffered.reject(error);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    }
    return executeRequest;
});
```

Here's the test code (this works perfectly when used for APIHelper or Config factory):

```
describe('Basic Injection Test', function() {

  var scope = {};
  var ctrl;

  beforeEach(module('Test'));

  it('should check if injection is being made correctly',function(){


      var $injector = angular.injector(['Test']);
      ctrl = $injector.get('XFactory');

    expect(ctrl).to.be.ok;
  });

});
```

Here's the files I'm including in karma.conf file:

```
  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '../angular.js',
        '../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../app.js',
        '../factory/APIHelper.js',
        '../factory/Config.js',
        '../factory/XFactory.js',
        'test.js'
    ],
```

NOTE: app.js has the following contents:

```
var app = angular.module('Test',[]);
```

app.js is just being used to help Karma find the Test module (before it was throwing an error that Test module cannot be found)

I'm using Karma for running the tests. The necessary files have been included in the "files" target of karma.conf.js file. However, when I run the tests, I get this error:

> **[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $qProvider  <-   $q    <- XFactory**

Even if I somehow remove the $q and $http services, I still get this error in this modified form:

> **[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: APIHelperProvider  <-   APIHelper    <- XFactory**

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error and also explain why this is happening? I'm new to Angular Unit Testing. Therefore, I don't really know how to solve this problem. Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`angular.injector` creates a new injector instance and doesn't load core `ng` module by default. `ng` and `ngMock` should be loaded explicitly:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngMock' 'Test']);
```

`APIHelper` service isn't defined in `Test` module and thus isn't available.

`module` affects nothing in this case because it refers to another injector (the one that is used by ngMock in specs.

Consider using instead the suggested injection method in specs, [`inject`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject).

Comment: This is how the APIHelper service is defined (in APIHelper.js)

angular.module('Test').factory('APIHelper', function() { 
    //code here
});

So isn't it defined in the Test module then?

Also, the code snippet you've provided, where should that be included in the test file?

Comment: Ok including this var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngMock', 'Test']); doesn't change anything

Comment: Does it still throw `$qProvider <- $q <- XFactory`? You haven't posted all the relevant code. It is not evident that file where `angular.module('Test').factory('APIHelper'...` is was loaded. And it is not evident that it was loaded after `angular.module('Test, [...])` module definition - it will throw an error otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it does.
Let me update the question description

Comment: I've added more information in the question to make things clear

Comment: I'm not aware of any condition that would cause `angular.injector(['ng', 'ngMock' 'Test'])` to throw `[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $qProvider <- $q <- XFactory`. It should either work or fail on bootstrapping. I would suggest to double-check that there are no other errors, and that  `angular.injector(['ng', ...` takes effect indeed. Have you tried `inject` to do the same thing? Is there any reason why you use `angular.injector` instead which isn't suitable for this task?

Comment: Yes, I did try using inject as well. That was giving me the same error. Do you think this has something to do with karma and how it reads the files?

When I try injecting the APIHelper file and comment out the XFactory.js file from the Karma file path, the test executes just fine. From what I know so far, I think it's the dependencies being referenced in the XFactory that's the problem.

Comment: The order in Karma looks correct, it is one of the reasons why retrieving a module with `angular.module('Test')` is bad - one module per file (e.g `angular.module('Test.XFactory', [...])`) is more solid construction because it doesn't depend on file order. For `inject` it is not possible to get `$qProvider <- $q` error physically. Make sure you don't use it together with `angular.injector`. Recreating the issue as fiddle/plunk (the working one that throws the same error) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out how to make it work. It was basically a Karma related problem. I simply changed the order of files that Karma was linking to. So I changed this:

```
  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '../angular.js',
        '../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../app.js',
        '../factory/APIHelper.js',
        '../factory/Config.js',
        '../factory/XFactory.js',
        'test.js'
    ],
```

To ***this***

```
  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '../angular.js',
        '../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../app.js',
        '../factory/Config.js',
        '../factory/APIHelper.js',
        '../factory/XFactory.js',
        'test.js'
    ],
```

I simply switched places of the Config file and the APIHelper file and that simply made the test pass.

Other than that, I think it might be helpful to mention here that any of the following syntax will work for injecting a service:

```
inject(function(_XFactory_){
    ctrl = _XFactory_;
});


inject(function($injector) {
   ctrl = $injector.get('XFactory');
}); 


angular.mock.inject(['XFactory', function(target) {

      expect(target).to.be.ok;

    }
]);
```